CSS box with curve arrow
I am trying to make this box with left down arrow.
Here is my current code :


.our-agency-processing::after {
  content: "Our Agency Processing";
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: #601eeb;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 17%;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-left: -25px;
}
<div class="row our-agency-processing">
  <div class="col">
    <h4 class="other-agencies">Other Agencies</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h4 class="our-agency">Our Agency</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    more code.....
  </div>
</div>



this is what i want:


https://css-generators.com/tooltip-speech-bubble/#t86
